# Brunch and RiotJS. Instantiating

Tags: javascript, brunch, riot.js

I'm having troubles using BrunchJS together with RiotJS (I'm new to both tools). My tags compile properly, however when attempting to "instantiate" them, it's all blank, as if they had no content.
Any ideas? Shouldn't I mount the component? Can I mount it not in the index file?
[Here](https://gist.github.com/git-toni/c28a0c626234fddc9558) there's a Gist with the relevant files. ( Including the compiled component, thanks to [riot-brunch](https://github.com/yavorsky/riot-brunch) plugin)

Comment: Maybe take a look at this example of Riot blog with Brunch: http://github.com/yavorsky/Riot-blog

Comment: yes, thanks! @yavorsky already replied via github. And he indeed directed me to that useful blog example :)